# Access variable saved in UIViewController from UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a MainViewController (MainVC.swift) and a CellViewController (CellVC.swift).
My MainViewController contains some labels, buttons, and a Collection View. The cell of this Collection View is controlled by CellViewController (I have a Cell.xib file).

In my MainViewController, I have saved some variables (floatRatingViewWidth, floatRatingViewHeight) I want to use in my CellViewController.

How can I access these variables from CellViewController?

**MainViewController**

```
class MainVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var floatRatingViewWidth = CGFloat()
    var floatRatingViewHeight = CGFloat()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "Cell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
 
        settingUpNavBar()
        
        let cellHeight = view.frame.size.height * 0.3
        let cellWidth = view.frame.size.width * 0.42
        
        floatRatingViewWidth = cellWidth - 69
        floatRatingViewHeight = cellHeight * 0.05

    }

}
```

**CellViewController**

```
class CellVC: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var ratingHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var ratingWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your cell add the vars that you need:

```
class CellVC: UICollectionViewCell {
    var cellFloatRatingViewWidth : CGFloat?
    var cellFloatRatingViewHeight = CGFloat?
```

In your:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
```

do:

```
cell.cellFloatRatingViewWidth = floatRatingViewWidth
```

Comment: Thank you! It works (but I access the outlets immediately)! Is there a possibility to do something like "let mainVC = MainVC()" and then access the data from the instance? I know that this code doesn´t work but maybe something similar to that?

Comment: This is not a good idea because you were working with a new instance of mainVC, so if any data changes, it will be different in each instance. What you can do is create a class with only variables, instantiate it in mainvc, set the data and pass the entire class.

Comment: Makes sense ^^ Thank you very much!